# International country database list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've found several databases out there, but none satisfies my needs.

Everywhere I looked had the country name written in english or some other language, but I need the country name to be written in the language of the target country itself.

For instance, I'm from "Brazil", but I need a database that the name it's written "Brasil", because that's how we call it here.

I'm preferably looking for a SQL database, but anything will do.

Comment: You are unlikely to get good answers to this question on SO because SO is more of a "how do I do ___ with this technology?", rather than "What is a good ___ for doing ___?" Read [How to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... I got tripped up on this one myself recently.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is have a country table such as:

```
create table country (
country_id integer
, country_name varchar(255)
, /* any other columns you want */
)
;
```

And then have a country translation lookup table like this:

```
create table country_translation (
country_id integer /* make it a foreign key on the country table pk */
, language_id integer /* make it a foreign key to a language table */
, country_translation varchar(255)
);
```

Then in your query you do something like this:

```
select coalesce(t.country_translation,c.country_name) country_name
from country c
   left join country_translation t on t.country_id = c.country_id
         and t.language_id = ? /* whatever language you feed it */
```

Then it will pull up the translated version dynamically based on the input language_id in the query, or will return the standardized english version.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you to checkout this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a database for countries. However, it may not satisfy your requirement of having names in the target country's language. Here's the [link](https://github.com/sagunkho/geo-sql-database) anyway.